# Developing Google gadgets with GWT

Tags: gwt, google-gadget, gwt-platform

I successfully created gadget using [Getting Started with Gadgets and GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/GadgetsGettingStarted)

I want to know:

1. Is it possible to work on gadgets in development mode? I want to change the code and see the results. Or i need to compile and publish the gadget every time i change code?
2. I want my GWT GAE application to be both normal GWT app and a google gadget. When user enters http://mygadget.appspot.com/ i want him to see normal GWT app. But when user access http://mygadget.appspot.com/axogadget/com.axdms.gadget.client.AxObjectGadget.gadget.xml he gets the gadget. Is it posible? Or it has to be 2 different GAE applications? (Normal GWT app and gadget have different functionality). Multiple entry points?

Answer (score 0):

1. yes using apache shinding, but it is still a hassle.
2. multiple entry points can work for you but you have to differentiate on how you make your calls to the server. Normal GWT app can use RPC for example but Gadgets must use IoProvider.